# How to avoid repeat selection on select query option?

Tags: php

I am having a problem to how avoid duplicates in my query, my code is like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">User:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <select type="text" name="user_id"  placeholder="User" >

                                        <option><?php

$sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from `user`,`appointment` where user.user_id = appointment.user_id and appointment.branch_id = $session_branchid")or die(mysql_error);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
echo "<option value=".$row["user_id"].">" .$row["firstname"].' '.$row["lastname"]. "</option>";

}
?></option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

the code is ok, but users are repeatedly in option selection?

Comment: Why you have `<option> .. PHP CODE .. </option>` and in PHP code have `<option>..</option>`?

Comment: Just use `Inner join`

Comment: should i do it like this? sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * from `user` INNER JOIN `appointment` ON (user.user_id = appointment.user_id) and (appointment.appoint_status = 'Confirmed') ")or die(mysql_error);

Comment: stachu, that is the value for the option, i used inner join like that, but there is still  repeat selectable on option?

Comment: there is still duplicate values on option? how do i avoid that

Comment: there is still duplicate values on option selection, I want to display only 1 username from user who have multiple appointment

Comment: You can try group by statement. And create alias for table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the SQL part to:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * from `user`,`appointment` where user.user_id = appointment.user_id and appointment.branch_id = $session_branchid")or die(mysql_error);
```

If the users' data are equal then the SQL will only return one record.

Comment: there is still repeated selectable on option?

Comment: there is still duplicate values on option selection, I want to display only 1 username from user who have multiple appointment

Comment: the try "SELECT DISTINCT user_id, firstname, lastname from user,appointment where user.user_id = appointment.user_id and appointment.branch_id = $session_branchid"

Comment: that is mysql_error, whats wrong with the query? I tried only user_id but wrong, cos user and appointment has same user_id

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT user.user_id, user.firstname, user.lastname FROM user INNER JOIN appointment ON user.user_id = apointment.user_id  WHERE  appointment.branch_id = $session_branchid

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio Be sure to accept an answer if it successfully solved your problem! That way, people will know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your query.

```
  SELECT * from `user` Join `appointment` ON ( user.user_id = appointment.user_id) where appointment.branch_id = $session_branchid
```

Comment: there is still duplicate values on option selection, I want to display only 1 username from user who have multiple appointment